# sqlite query using WHERE and AND in android studio

Tags: android, sqlite

So I am trying to select the count where a value = value* conditional to another boolean value being true. I wrote a query as such I am new to sqlite so I am sorry in advance for syntax:

```
public int getPlaceCount(String name){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + TABLE + " WHERE " + NAME + " = ? AND " + CURRENT + " <> ?";
    String value = "0";
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(query,new String[]{name,value});
    int count = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("COUNT(*)"));
    return count;
}
```

now in mysql I would do something like this:

```
select count(*) from TABLE where NAME='name' and CURRENT=1;
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I needed to move cursor to first:

```
cursor.moveToFirst();
```